# SQLite and Ruby rescue

Tags: ruby, hash, syntax, sqlite

I'm following the pretty great SLite & Ruby tutorial over at [ZetCode](http://zetcode.com/db/sqliteruby/) and have run into a silly question. What exactly is going on here?

```
rescue SQLite3::Exception => e 

    puts "Exception occured"
    puts e
```

I conceptually get what's happening: if an exception is raised, it gets printed on the screen. But what is this syntax, specifically?

```
SQLite3::Exception => e
```

Is there another simple example of where I'd use the hash rocket like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rescue` statement has an unusual use for that notation. It means "capture the exception of type `SQLite3::Exception` into the variable `e`":

```
rescue SQLite3::Exception => e
```

You're not required to capture the exception into a variable, you can omit that part if you don't need it, and you don't need to specify the exception kind, either, which will default to the exception base class `Exception`.

The syntax is only coincidentally the same as the hash declaration presumably to promote consistency. The two are not otherwise related.

Comment: The statement is equivalent to Java's `} catch (SQLiteException e) {`